# loading 700 ng-options inside ng-repeat with 200 records, browser crash

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have an ng-repeat with a a few hundred items. Within each item I'm loading a select element with 700 options. This is a bit too much for the browser.

Does anyone have  a solution for this?
Is there a load on demand directive out there?

Comment: So you have 200 select boxes, each with 700 select options?  You don't need angular.  You need a better UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom angular select directive that generate options only if you click on it.
Like

- https://github.com/singlecomm/angular-sc-select
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/